# Postgresql : Clone schema remotely

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, remote-server

**Context :** 
Actually I have a bot/parser that use API to grab data from an online Game, there is a lot of API call, so it works for few worlds.
But this game have more than 200 worlds, so my main server can't do it alone.
So I decided to use two, three more servers (VPS for example) to do this job.

So I have :

- One server with one (Main) PostgreSQL DB and JAVA BackOffice to serve this data through webservices to a front end.
- Multiples VPS with one batch on each : theses VPS are calling the API and grab data for specifics worlds (for example each VPS grap data for 100 worlds)
  Once it's done theses VPS calculate stats with this data.

**Problem :** How can I send data from VPS to my main Database.

I decided to install a postgresql data base on each VPS so I can grab data and calculate statistics on theses server.
And then I would like to send thisdata to my main server programmatically. Each world are stored in a specific Schema (eg world{id_world})
I know how to clone schema in the same database : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Clone_schema

**Question :** How can I clone schema from VPS to main server ? (remotely)

Thanks ! :)

*Note : if you think that It's a bad Idea to do this you can told me why in comments*

Comment: You can use Foreign Data Wrappers for PostgreSQL. Does that solve your problem? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#postgres_fdw

Comment: It sounds interesting, but It's only available in 9.3 and 9.4 and I'm still in 9.1 (because it's the most used version of PostgresQL)

But yeah it seems to be a good solution for thoses who want to do that :)

Comment: OK. This (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/dblink.html) is a rough equivalent of data wrappers.